# Access SPO List from a different site collection through provider hosted addin

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin, csom

Ok so the title pretty much sums it up. I've got a developer site, i create a sharepoint addin and i can get all the information from there with no problems.

The problem is i actually want to work on a DIFFERENT site collection (get information from some lists, do some things in the backend etc etc). Its the same tenant, but a different site collection.

The Sharepoint Provider Hosted Add-in creates a client context FOR the site that it is created on (in this case the developer site, meant for testing). Is there any way for me to access a different site collection without asking for credentials/hardcoding them?

I know there's a way to create client context by hardcoding credentials, but its not usefull to me (i will to check which user visited so i can limit some things, thats where the SP Addin client context comes in). If i do it without credentials....i just get 403 cause it has no connection to the site i need to access.

Hopefully i made this clear and you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently except the SideLoading of apps on another site collection i have found no way to do it.

I have, however, found a neat new feature of SPO which is a Site specific App Catalogue (installed by using powershell, i contacted my firms IT for it). The site specific App Catalogue does what it says. It lets you install apps only available for that site collection.